# Ubuntu crashed while updating

Tags: upgrade

I am using Ubuntu for 4 years. Now I have loaded 64 bit version on my Home. while upgrading to 12.4 it was interrupted for some reasons and not full upgrade down loaded. I started Ubuntu on some next 2 days after it was working fine then when connected to internet I saw that 1120 updates are waiting. I started updating when all updates downloaded and it started processing the updates it stopped in between and Ubuntu in now not opening. what should I do? I have Windows as well as Ubuntu on same hard-disk on my computer. Whether any remedy or I have to fresh load Ubuntu?

Comment: Close voters: This question has a good answer. **There is no need to close this**.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally opt for a clean install.

Boot to a LiveCD, backup your home files (which should all be accessible still) and any others that you want to keep to another drive and reinstall. The whole process takes about half an hour (depending on how much stuff you have) and you get a shiny clean install.

You might want to try recovering the upgrade process first - just in case it's that simple. From the LiveCD, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt # swap sdXY for your drive/partition
sudo chroot /mnt
apt-get update
apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Are you sure `apt-get` is going to work, without `/proc` or `/dev` mounted and without setting any environment variables?